# Multi diemensional array foreach key item php

Tags: php, arrays

**Array**

```
    [1] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [id] =&gt; 17
                    [model] =&gt; SB125T-23B
                    [file] =&gt; SB125T-23B_Blue
                    [color] =&gt; Blue
                    [hex] =&gt; 0033ff-3c3c3c
                    [active] =&gt; 1
                )

            [1] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [id] =&gt; 18
                    [model] =&gt; SB125T-23B
                    [file] =&gt; SB125T-23B_Red
                    [color] =&gt; Red
                    [hex] =&gt; CC0000-3c3c3c
                    [active] =&gt; 1
                )

        )
```

**PHP Code**

```
foreach ($threeSixty[0] as $key => $value) { 
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) { 
        echo $threeSixty[$key][$v];
    }
}
```

I have this array and PHP code. i am trying to loop through the outer array to get to the inner arrays. Then looping through those i am trying to get to the data under file. Doing it how i have it at the moment just returns the value for each data item. so id then model and so forth.

how can i do it so i can access the file so **echo $threeSixty[0]['file'];** for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using your value `$v` as a key - use `$k` instead. Also, unless you have an array in an array in an array - don't specify the index in the first loop. (I think you have an array in an array :-)

```
foreach ($threeSixty as $key => $value) { 
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) { 
        echo $threeSixty[$key][$k];
    }
}
```

To get just `file`:

```
foreach ($threeSixty as $key => $value) { 
    echo $threeSixty[$key]['file'];
}
```

To get `file` for only one:

```
echo $threeSixty[0]['file'];
```

Edit: I am assuming that `$threeSixty` looks something like this:

```
$threeSixty = array(
    array(
        'id' => '17',
        'model' => 'SB125T-23B',
        'file' => 'SB125T-23B_Blue',
        'color' => 'Blue',
        'hex' => '0033ff-3c3c3c',
        'active' => '1'
    )
);
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at php iterators such as http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php

Comment: Hi, thanks but that gives me zero for the key of the first array key. How can i get the value in the file part.

Comment: Hi @user3004208 - is your array in the same format as the one in my answer? Or does your array have another level?

Comment: no thats the format of the array itll only ever be like that so one or more arrays in an array

Comment: Are you sure yours is not like this `$threeSixy = array(array(array()))` - mine is just `array(array())`